# While deleting a user entity in hibernate the role get deleted as well

Tags: java, hibernate

I have 3 tables:

```
user: (id,username,password)
role: (id,role)
user_roles: (user_id, role_id)
```

and the following two Hibernate entities:

User:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User implements Serializable{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String userName;
    private String password;
    private boolean active = false;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER )
    @JoinTable(name = "user_roles", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id") })
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<Role>();
....
```

Role:

```
@Entity
@Table (name = "roles")
public class Role implements Serializable {
@Id @GeneratedValue
private Long id;
private String role;
....
```

When I delete now a User the corresponding role get deleted as well from the "role" table instead to delete just the user row and the user_roles relation. Even if other users are still related to that role. I use the following to delete the user.

```
@Transactional
public void deleteByName(String userName) {
    User user = this.getByName(userName);
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    session.delete(user);
}
```

Anyone know why and how to solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expected behaviour for the current mapping. It is configured by the `cascade` setting:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER )
private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<Role>();
```

If you do not want the roles to be removed when a user is, you will have to narrow down your cascade settings. Right now you are using `ALL`. This is equivalent to `{PERSIST, REMOVE, REFRESH, MERGE, DETACH}`. Decide on which ones you need and remove the others.

There is one thing I did not understand. You say that the roles are removed "Even if other users are still related to that role". This should not be possible.

The relationship of `Role` and `User` is a many-to-one, so there can be only one user attached to a role.

Comment: be sure that remove cacade its not also on the database

Comment: I simply assumed there is none, as the behaviour configuration by the cascade would be redundant. If the remove cascade is gone but the cascaded removal still occurs, I would look into the DB.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I just noticed that my problem is the OneToMany relationship. When I create the user I use mostly the same roles. for example "USER_ROLE" for user1 and user2. I probably need a ManyToMany relationship. Is that right?

Comment: You're welcome :) A many-to-many relationship is a more natural fit for users and their roles. However watch out for the cascading settings.

Comment: So far the user row is deleted and the user_roles row is deleted instead of the role row, when replacing OneToMany with ManyToMany and removing the cascade settings. It works. Also creating a User and relating it to role works now. Thanks